# ms access horizontal multilevel navigation bar or menu

Tags: ms-access

I would like to ask somebody, if in MS Access 2010 is possible to somehow create
form with horizontal multilevel navigation bar or menu, similar to which can be done in javascript or jQuery and which we can found on almost every web page.

[For example something similar to this ...](http://red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/css3-animated-dropdown-menu-demo.html)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

New for Access 2010 (and beyond) is the new navigation form system. While they dont' "hover" drop down like your "bootstrap" example, they are classic web like menus. So they look like this:

[image]

The above shows when the tab is clicked on, you CAN EASY add a second row to that (so you get the same essential navigation result as per your example.

Not only can navigation go across the top but when selecting you CAN THEN have the menu go go down the left side (again like near all web sites do). In fact here I use a "left side" navigation form in this video without the top menu bar:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI&feature=player_detailpage

So you can as noted used BOTH at once.

Comment: This is slick. Why have I not used this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is not a built in way to do this.

I was able to sort of replicate this. On my form I made a frame and two comboboxes. I put the two comboboxes snug together and then sung inside the frame. You could make the frame the same color as your background so it is essentially invisible.

[image]

In my form my code is like this

```
Private Sub ComboLeft_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    ComboLeft.SetFocus
    ComboLeft.Dropdown
End Sub

Private Sub ComboRight_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    ComboRight.SetFocus
    ComboRight.Dropdown
End Sub

Private Sub Frame_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Frame.SetFocus
End Sub
```

You can see the frame is necessary to close the 'menus' when you leave the menu area. You could put labels over top of the comboboxes too and have the same code run off the mousemove event for the label. that way you don't see the value of the combobox.

When a user clicks a 'menu item' you can handle the click event on that combobox to do the appropriate action.